# Should a public web site which only displays data need SSL to be set up

Tags: tomcat, ssl, amazon-rds

I have a tiny web application which is to be launched publicly on internet. It serves as a Wiki to another application and reads from the second application's  Amazon RDS database instance and we are talking about just two DB tables.

The application only has two pages to display data and doesn't take anything back. The web site is publicly available to anyone and doesn't use any authentication mechanism. The web site doesn't also contain any confidential data as well.

This application is developed using Java with Hibernate connected to an Amazon RDS instance, JQuery and is supposed to be run on a Tomcat server.

My question is, would such a minimal application need to be made secure. If yes, what would be the best thing to do?

Many thanks..!

Comment: If your users submit confidential data then you should use https in order to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: My users do not submit any kind of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confidentiality is just one of the pillars of SSL; the other two being integrity and authenticity. If you want users accessing yoursite-com to be certain that they are accessing yoursite-com and/ or ensure that they are seeing data as served by you and not manipulated by anyone, you should use HTTPS.

There are other factors like [Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/04/30/deprecating-non-secure-http/) and [Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/marking-http-as-non-secure) considering deprecating non-HTTPS pages (insecure indicators like a red crossed-out padlock and/ or restricted functionality) in the not too distant future and Google already including HTTPS as a [positive ranking signal](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal_6.html) in search results.

Comment: This tiny application serves as a wiki to another application. It would only be used by the users of that particular application. So, I am not concerned about ranking. But, deprecating the non HTTPS web sites should definitely be considered.